# React + Spring Boot "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Tags: reactjs, spring, mongodb, web

I'm just starting out with web development. I'm currently trying to build something using Spring Boot, React.js and MongoDB. I use port 8080 for Spring Boot and port 3000 for react. I link the ports with ngrok. This already works with @CrossOrigin in the controller classes. However, when I want to retrieve information from the database, the browser console gives the following error message: "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED". I also packed @CrossOrigin into my service classes, but that doesn't help either. Does anyone have any idea how to fix the error?